# How do I concat more many Data Frames in python?

Tags: python

This the code i was trying to run

```
import pandas as pd
import os

jan = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\1 January.csv")
feb = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\2 February.csv")
mar = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\3 March.csv")
apr = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\4 April.csv")
may = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\5 May.csv")
jun = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\6 June.csv")
jul = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\7 July.csv")
aug = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\8 August.csv")
sep = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\9 September.csv")
oco = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\10 October.csv")
nov = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\11 November.csv")
dec = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\octave\12 December.csv")

meg = [jan,feb, mar, apr, may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oco,nov, dec]
df = pd.concat(meg)
```

but it was trowing this error message

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-08053c8d7ca6> in <module>
```

please how do I resolve it?

Comment: Please Post Complete code.

Comment: What is the size of your dataframes?

Comment: @Huzefa I have posted the complete code

Comment: @PrakashDahal over 500,000 records for each DataFrame

Comment: So thats why you are getting memory error

Comment: @ Michael Mololuwa do you want to take data from all the files and import that as a single dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want data from all the csv files into a single csv file:

```
# Import the Libraries
import os
import pandas as pd


# List Files
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files


# Pick CSV Files

files = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'csv']
files


## Initialize Empty df and loop over files and add data to the df
data=pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    data = df.append(data)
    
    
    
data.head()

data.to_excel('data.xlsx')
```

If the csv files are not present in the same location change the location using os.cwd

an example of using the same is:

```
os.cwd('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Test')
```

Comment: Thank you @Daharman when i tried the code.. it throw this error 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'1 January.csv' does not exist: b'1 January.csv

Comment: @Micheal Mololuwa just see the complete path of the file and use os.chdir command as explained

Comment: The error itself is self explanatory the file is not found at the location specified

Answer (score 1):

Since it is causing you memory error, I recommend you to concat all the csv files in one csv files and read using `pd.read_csv` instead of reading and then concating. You should also delete their instances to free more memory.

```py
jan.to_csv('month.csv')
feb.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)
mar.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)
apr.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)
may.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)
jun.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)
jul.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)
aug.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)
sep.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)
oco.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)
nov.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)
dec.to_csv('month.csv', mode='a', columns=False)

#Delete the instances
del jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oco, nov, dec


final_df = pd.read_csv('month.csv')
```

Well reading the large file also may cause you memory error. So read the files using `chunksize` or using dask.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
final_df = dd.read_csv('month.csv')
```